# Is this a bug in Transaction mechanism in javacards?

Tags: transactions, smartcard, javacard

I wrote the below program and upload it on my card :

```
package transactionMechanismBugCheck;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;

public class TransactionMechanismBugCheck extends Applet {
    short[] arrayS;
    byte[] arrayB;

    private TransactionMechanismBugCheck() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new TransactionMechanismBugCheck().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {

        short[] arraySlocal=null;

        JCSystem.beginTransaction();
            arrayS=new short[1];
            arraySlocal=arrayS;
        JCSystem.abortTransaction();

        ISOException.throwIt((short)0x9001); 
    } 
}
```

Installing procedure :

```
gp: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)


gp: gp -install d:\transactionMechanismBugCheck.cap

gp: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 010203040506 (|......|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     010203040506 (|......|)


gp:
```

**The question is: Why I don't receive `SW=0x9001` in respond of selection?**

[image]

Above,The cursor blinking for about 10 second and then below line appears:

```
OSC: opensc-tool -s 00A4040006010203040506
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 06
APDU transmit failed: Transmit failed

OSC:
```

Note that I read this [article](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~mostowskiwi/papers/wissec2009.pdf) that is for 2009!

**1- Why it doesn't respond to my select command with the exception that I put in the program?**

**2-Does this mean my javacard is vulnerable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we cannot look into the card, it seems a higher chance that there *is* protection against this attack and that a countermeasure has been triggered. A useful countermeasure is to "mute" the card, so no information is leaked back to a possible attacker. This *may* mean that the card is *not vulnerable*.

There is of course no way to tell for sure, ask the vendor instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `JCSystem.abortTransaction()` when creating new objects as it may result to session lock or force tear/reset as what probably happened in your case.

Please see this link for more info:
http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/JCSystem.html#abortTransaction()

No, your JavaCard is not directly vulnerable. But your design is if you do not use these methods properly.

Comment: I played the role of an attacker, and not the programmer. I wanted to know, if somebody wrote a program in this way, can he gain the information of other applets or not

Comment: I would be very surprised if the Java Card API itself forced a card tear :)